# SQLCipher on J2SE

Tags: java, sqlcipher

I am trying to use SQLCipher in my desktop J2SE application.  According to the SQLCipher website Java is supported.  We currently use it in our Android application, but I have no idea where to start on the J2SE side?  There is not much out there on the topic.  I have seen a little about building the JDBC driver, but I did not really want to start anything until I was fully informed.  Can anyone provide any direction?

Comment: Crosspost from Mailing list: We don't offer a J2SE library for SQLCipher at this time. That said, we've 
done some initial work on one, but put the project on hold due to lack of 
interest (at the time). 
I'm curious to know from you, and the rest of the list if anyone else would 
care to chime in - is there interest in a Commercial Edition driver for 
SQLCipher on J2SE, sold through the Zetetic Store like the other commercial 
editions at a similar price point? 
Let me know what you think.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/55070630/1663987 for additional information and a source for a java JDBC SQLCipher library