# MySQL: REQUIRE SSL not shown in grants

Tags: mysql

MySQL 8 doesn't show `REQUIRE SSL` in the `SHOW GRANTS` output.

On MariaDB, when I create a user using `REQUIRE SSL`, it is shown in the grants:

```
Server version: 10.2.22-MariaDB MariaDB Server

MariaDB [(none)]> drop user if exists 'test'; 
MariaDB [(none)]> create user 'test' REQUIRE SSL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'test';
+----------------------------------------------+
| Grants for test@%                            |
+----------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test'@'%' REQUIRE SSL |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

But in MySQL8, I don't see `REQUIRE SSL` indicated:

```
mysql> drop user if exists 'testu';
mysql> create user 'testu' REQUIRE SSL;
mysql> show grants for 'test';
+----------------------------------+
| Grants for test@%                |
+----------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `test`@`%` |
+----------------------------------+
```

Attempting to connect without SSL does properly give an error, but how can I see which users have it enabled if it's not shown in the grants?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mysql [localhost:8014] {msandbox} ((none)) > show create user 'test';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER for test@%                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' REQUIRE SSL ... |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-user.html