# How to check if a user requires SSL in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-rds

I'am testing with an AWS RDS Mysql instance with Mysql verison 5.7.22.

After [requiring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport) ssl for a specific user, 'root' (GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;"), this is the result of SHOW GRANTS for root;

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD,
  PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, 
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, 
 REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, 
ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' 
 WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there anyway I can check to see that ssl is required for a user? Show grants output doesn't mention ssl. I would think that Show grants is the right command to use because ssl was initially required on the user via GRANT USAGE.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070630/mysql-require-ssl-not-shown-in-grants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I found was that from the client, you can run [status](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/how-can-i-verify-im-using-ssl-to-connect-to-mysql) to determine if the current connection is using ssl. Not sure if there's a way to do it for a specific user though.

### Edit

Chris White's solution([MySQL: REQUIRE SSL not shown in grants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070630/mysql-require-ssl-not-shown-in-grants)) works for a specific user

Answer (score 7):

Here you can see all users with REQUIRE SSL (works on MySQL 5.7 and others):

```
SELECT *
FROM mysql.user
WHERE ssl_type <> '';
```

Answer (score 1):

##### With DDL (easier)

You can get the DDL of your user as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-user.html) with:

`SHOW CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost';`

Then check if you find a `REQUIRE SSL` in the create user request displayed.

##### With `status` command

As stated by @committedandroider you can use the `status` command to see if your current user is logged in using SSL. If it's written `SSL: Not in use` you're currently not using it.

To force a connection without SSL you can use `--skip-ssl` or on new mysql versions the [`--ssl-mode=DISABLED` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-options.html#option_general_ssl): `mysql -u username -p --ssl-mode=DISABLED`. If you get an access denied it's probably because ssl is required (but it can be caused by something else so I'll prefer to use the DDL option). In newer versions you