# Why am I getting this "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" error after trying to run "Status" with pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

This is a follow up to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203365/how-to-check-if-a-user-requires-ssl-in-mysql) I had earlier

To check a certain user requires SSL, my current approach is to log as the user and run status and check the SSL line of the output - for ex) -(SSL: Not in use)

This is the code I have to do so

```
conn = pymysql.connect(...)

try:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("STATUS")
        print(cur.fetchAll())
finally:
    conn.close()
```

When I run this, I'am getting this error - "(1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STATUS' at line 1")"

I'am confused because "STATUS" is valid Mysql Syntax - I'am able to run that this command after connecting to the Mysql database via mysql linux client. Does anyone familiar with PyMysql/Python/Mysql know what changes I need to make to this query to make this work?

Comment: Did you mean `"SHOW STATUS"`?

Comment: @ChrisWhite no I'am trying to run this command - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/how-can-i-verify-im-using-ssl-to-connect-to-mysql

Comment: Think I figured it out though. What I referenced isn't a Mysql query. It's a command you run on the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I was trying to run was status - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/how-can-i-verify-im-using-ssl-to-connect-to-mysql. But the issue is that that command is a client side command, not a SQL query. "Show Status" is a sql query.